# MySQL UNION ALL performance tuning

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, union-all

```
SELECT `col1` FROM `tbl1`;   -- takes 0.0022s

SELECT `col1` FROM `tbl2`;   -- takes 0.0017s

SELECT `col1` FROM `tbl1`
UNION ALL 
(SELECT `col1` FROM `tbl2`); -- takes 0.1100s
```

Why `UNION ALL` working slow?

Any other alternative of using `UNION ALL`?

Comment: Provide `EXPLAIN` plan for your query

Comment: try avoid the () around the second select

Comment: @scaisEdge It does not matter, after removing it returning the same output costing same time

Comment: @MKhalidJunaid Can you elaborate? I used explain sql but i wanted to know the reason why union all slows two sql down,

Comment: @MD.KamruzZamanRana To know the reason first you have to look into  [Obtaining Execution Plan Information](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/explain.html)

Comment: @scaisEdge - I respond to your suggestion on the () in my Answer.

Comment: Which version of MySQL?

Answer (score 2):

Is the [Query Cache](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/query-cache.html) turned on?  It could be that the two individual `SELECTs` are artificially fast due to getting the resultset from the QC.

Let's dissect the `UNION` to understand its sluggishness:

1. Create a temp table for the resultset.
2. Perform first `SELECT`, writing results to that temp.
3. Perform second `SELECT`, writing results to that temp.
4. Read the temp table.
5. (De-duplicate. This did not happen since you said `ALL` on `UNION`.)
6. Deliver the results to the client.
7. Drop the temp table.

Two things are probably aggravating the situation:

- Windows is slower than *NIX at building tables.
- It was not until a very recent versions of MySQL that *some* `UNIONs` can avoid the temp table. That is, in the future, the results from each `SELECT` can be delivered directly to the client. You apparently do not have such version.

As for the parentheses, leave them on. Put them on the other `SELECT`, too. It does not impact performance, but it *may* impact the result.  Imagine, for example, what the `GROUP BY` applies to in these three cases:

```
-- Case 1
SELECT ..     UNION SELECT ..   GROUP BY ..

-- Case 2
SELECT ..     UNION ( SELECT ..   GROUP BY .. )

-- Case 3
( SELECT .. ) UNION ( SELECT .. ) GROUP BY ..
```

The first one is the same as the second, not the third.